# Vue js i need to compress file to gzip and send it to the back-end

Tags: javascript, vue.js, compression, gzip

I have installed npm install compressing
and i'm getting this error:
how can i compress file to zip in vuejs 2.6?

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fs'
    at webpackMissingModule (webpack:///./node_modules/compressing/lib/utils.js?:3)
    at Object.eval (webpack:///./node_modules/compressing/lib/utils.js?:3)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/compressing/lib/utils.js?:199)
    at Object../node_modules/compressing/lib/utils.js (front.js:8020)
    at __webpack_require__ (front.js:790)
    at fn (front.js:101)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/compressing/lib/zip/index.js?:3)
    at Object../node_modules/compressing/lib/zip/index.js (front.js:8044)
    at __webpack_require__ (front.js:790)
    at fn (front.js:101)
```

How to compress to gltf ?

Comment: That error occurs because VueJS is as you might know run on the client. The client or browser can not use the Node module `fs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer from anther question that i had: pako (npm pako)
solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

[Compressing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compressing) module is for Node. Use another package which is not dependent on filesystem like [jszip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip)

Comment: is there away to compress my.txt to gzip in vue js ?

Comment: It's not a vue.js responsibility to archive content. You should use external packages like jszip for this task. Use input (type=file) to get a file content and zip it with jszip afterwards.

Comment: i see that i can use it to zip is it good also for gzip ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you want to use gzip to compress files on a server for faster website access from a client then you need to tweak a webserver settings. If you want to provide to a user a feature to upload a file from a website to your server with compressing then jszip is a good choice.

Comment: the backend dev told me to send gzip file, he told me compress it and send it by post to the controller, this is what i'm trying to do

Comment: Yes, jszip will help you with this task.

Comment: how can i send it a a gzip file instead of zip ?